# Proguard android keep class

Tags: android

I've enabled android proguard. After sing in i've run my app  on device. its throws below error.

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:355)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
    at lf.a(Source:481)
    at lf.onPostExecute(Source:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What class need to keep in proguard? if disable proguard its working correctly.

Comment: Did you get this error when you run it normally without Proguard? The error looks like you trying to format a null as a number - which is not possible in Java/Android.

Comment: If disable the proguard ,its working correctly .

Comment: any library you have added to your project should be kept like facebook SDK or Google play services.

Comment: Before we conclude anything, perhaps you need to look at **class lf** at **line 481** and see if you have properly check for null before formatting a value as a number. Note: You may need to de-obfuscate class `lf` to see what Proguard is actually referring to.